# how to record reflexive entity in DB?

Tags: algorithm, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a reflexive entity, a classic parent - children.

This hierarchy is edited by the user in the front-end and then passed back to the backend.

The only way I've found to record that kind of array with doctrine/symfony2 is this way (ps no code, logic here):

1. getting the modified array array_result
2. getting all the objects from the bdd (via the repository, I get an array of all the objects) array_bdd
3. loop over array_result, each element of the modified array
4. if element.id can be found in array_bdd then
5. comparing all the properties
6. if there is a difference in the properties, I modify the object in array_bdd and persist it
7. end of loop
8. flush

It's seems a bit heavy to me but from what I've read I couldn't find another way.

Is it correct to perform like this with doctrine ?

Comment: You can also have a look to `StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle` that integrate the `DoctrineExtensions` library to the Framework. There is an extensions called `Tree` that may suit your needs.

Comment: actually I use it already. It's very usefull to extract the data from the DB and have it in form of a tree in a single query. But it doesn't provide a function to save the entire modified array.

Comment: OK, I'm sorry but I'm not sure I understand what your are trying to do, so...